# Why does my LinearLayout with weights leave a pixel space at the bottom for some dimension combinations?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android

I'm building a UI with LinearLayout where I specify relative sizes using `layout_weight`.  I am seeing an issue where certain combinations of weights will result in a tiny space at the bottom of the screen.  I was under the impression that it would scale each child view such that they completely fill the parent LinearLayout - is that not true?  How can I use the proportions I want yet prevent a space from showing at the bottom?

This happens for all screen sizes that I've tried in the Android Studio layout tool.

These (undesired) weights result in screen being completely filled:
0.15, 0.75, 0.05

These (desired) weights result in the tiny space at the bottom: 0.15, 0.75, 0.1

[image: screenshot]

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#22FF22"
    tools:context="...">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:textSize="31dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/blue90"
        android:text="HEADER" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_workout_selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">
        </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue90"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to use integers value with the same proportion 3, 15, 1

Comment: sum of all weights that given to the child views should be 1  OR giva weightsum attribute as the sum your weights eg: 0.05+0.15+0.75

Comment: As I note below, the issue also shows up on devices, not just the Android Studio layout tool.  The fix was to multiply the weights by 10.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to solely be an Android Studio glitch (which I suspect is due to the way it handles float values for weights), i.e. it won't be replicated on real devices. If it's bugging you, just multiply each weight by 100.

Comment: The issue actually showed up on real devices (at least on a Galaxy S2).  Multiplying the weights by 10 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to multiply the desired weights by 10:

1.5, 7.5, 1

Must be some rounding issue caused by small fractional weights.